# Reading parse objects with cloud code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm approaching Parse Cloud Code at the moment and to learn i'm checking some basic examples.
I have a class named MeetingObject in my parse data base. This class has a field "meetingDateAndTime".
I created a background job that check for objects older than the current time and destroy them. I would like the see in the parse Info Log the objectId of the destroyed objects but i can only see the success message, not the log. I tried also using result.objectId. Maybe the "result" variable i'm using is not an Array. What am i doing wrong?

```
Parse.Cloud.job("deleteOldMeetings", function(request, status) {
var query = new Parse.Query("MeetingObject");            
var currentDate = new Date();                
query.lessThan("meetingDateAndTime", currentDate);
query.find({          
success:function(results) {   
    for (var i = 0, len = results.length; i < len; i++) {
        var result = results[i];
        console.log("Destroyed object.objectId: "+result.get("objectId"));
        result.destroy({});
    }
    status.success("Success.");
},                
error: function(error) {
    status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
    console.log("Failed!");
}
})
});
```

Comment: Are the objects being destroyed?

Comment: Try moving the console.log statement immediately above the call to destroy. Also, the correct parse.com syntax for getting an attribute of an object is to use get: result.get("objectId"), not result["objectId"]. You should also consider using the destroyAll method, to destroy a list of objects in one operation.

Comment: I edited the code with the changes you suggested and tried in parse and the log is this: "Destroyed object.objectId: undefined". I would prefer to use the simple destroy instead of destroyAll because i need to do also some changes on the user that created the meeting so maybe it's best to make these changes in the loop.

Comment: Ok. For the object id, I think you can use just id. result.id. But you can't log that after you have destroyed it. That's probably why you didn't see anything in the logs.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot. If you want to write an answer i will accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To get the id of a parse object called "thing": `thing.id`
- To get any other attribute (call it "attr") of a parse object called "thing": `thing.get("attr")`
- You can't refer to an object after it has been destroyed.